# Resampling many timeseries files with pandas/dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have many `.csv` files with two columns. One with timestamps and the other with values. The data is sampled on seconds. What I would like to do is

- read all files
- set index on time column
- resample on hours
- save to new files (parquet, hdf,...)

**1) Only `dask`**

I tried to use `dask`'s `read_csv`.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = dd.read_csv(
    "../data_*.csv",
    parse_dates = [0],
    date_parser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(float(x)),
)
```

So far that's fine. The problem is that I cannot `df.resample("min").mean()` directly, because the index of dask data frame is not properly set.

After calling `dd.reset_index().set_index("timestamp")` it works - **BUT**  I cannot afford to do this because it is expensive.

**2) Workaround with `pandas` and `hdf` files**

Another approach was to save all `csv` files to `hdf` files using pandas. In this case the pandas dataframes were already indexed by time.

```
df= dd.read_hdf("/data_01.hdf", key="data")

# This doesn't work directly
# df = df.resample("min").mean()
# Error: "Can only resample dataframes with known divisions"

df = df.reset_index().set_index("timestamp")  # expensive! :-(
df = df.resample("min").mean()  # works!
```

Of course this works but it would be extremely expensive on `dd.read_hdf("/data_*.hdf", key="data")`.

How can I directly read timeseries data in dask that it is properly partitioned and indexed?
Do you have any tips or suggestions?

---

Exmpample Data:

```
import dask

df = dask.datasets.timeseries()
df.to_hdf("dask.hdf", "data")

# Doesn't work!
# dd.read_hdf("dask.hdf", key="data").resample("min").mean()

# Works!
dd.read_hdf("dask.hdf", key="data").reset_index().set_index("timestamp").resample(
    "min"
).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col='timestamp', parse_dates=['timestamp']) \
  .resample('T').mean().to_csv('data_1min.csv')  # or to_hdf(...)
```

Comment: Yes technically this is possible of course. It assumes that I do not have to resample across two files by the given resampling frequency. Afterwards it would be the same problem again to have the resampled dataset as nicely partitioned data in dask dataframes.

Comment: Your data are continuous between 2 files? I mean there are common timestamps between files?

Comment: Not common between two files but what happens when the first thrity minutes are at the end of file 1 and the second thrity minutes are in file 2 with resampling requency 1 hour?